# Generating Binary columns based on string column which needs splitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas column, which is shown as below.

```
finalDF['question.DAL_negative_countries_MX_BR_VE']

0                                                     NaN
1                                                   China
2                                                     NaN
                              ...                        
9787                                        United States
9788    United States | China | France | Germany | Uni...
```

I want to generate individual binary columns for each response option (country). For example, one of the generated binary columns can be "question.DAL_positive_countries_MX_BR_VE_United_States" containing 1 if the respondent selected "United_States", and 0 otherwise.

I know to do df.col.str.split('|') but doesn't create binary columns as I need.

Comment: Try `df.col.str.get_dummies`?

Comment: yes, it works, but it gives me repeated columns, such as for canada, US, there are two binary columns, maybe that is due to whitespace or something, is there any way to solve that as well. Thanks

Comment: Please see this, there are more than two columns for same countries. https://ibb.co/KLXryYB

Comment: You can select unique countries in separate pandas series first, and then create dummies

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample data?